# how to create custom shortcuts for scrot and gnome-screenshot interactive mode

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome3

I want to add command **scrot -s** as custom shortcuts via **gnome-control-center keyboard**. The accelerator key was Super+S.

[image]

but it didn't works.

If i remove **-s** or try other interactive command like **xkill**, they works fine.

Also, **scrot -e 'mv $f ~/Pictures/scrot/'** is works fine too.

So my question, why **scrot -s** didn't work and how can i fix it.

My distro is fedora 21, gnome version is 3.14.2, and scrot version 0.8

**[UPDATE]** **gnome-screenshot -a** is failed too.

**[UPDATE 2]** The default shortcut "Save a screenshot of an area to Pictures" is working fine, but i'm still curious why it didn't work when i set it to custom shortcuts.
[image]

**[UPDATE 3]**
The following is the error log results from custom shortcut command `strace -v -s 1000000 -o /tmp/gnomescr.log gnome-screenshot -a`:

```
$ grep -ni CRITICAL /tmp/gnomescr.log 
2660:write(2, "\n(gnome-screenshot:8700): Gdk-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_get_from_surface: assertion 'width > 0 && height > 0' failed\n", 115) = 115
2686:write(2, "\n(gnome-screenshot:8700): Gtk-CRITICAL **: gtk_window_resize: assertion 'width > 0' failed\n", 91) = 91
2748:write(2, "\n** (gnome-screenshot:8700): CRITICAL **: Unable to capture a screenshot of any window\n", 87) = 87
$
```

Comment: Create a script with these contents: `scrot -s 2>~/scrot_error` and run the script with your shortcut. Then, post the content of `~/scrot_error`.

Comment: There's empty file created if i run sh ~/test.sh from terminal, but no file created if i run it as a shortcut command, i.e. sh ~/test.sh. I tried strace for scrot and the error is "write(2, "giblib error: ", 14)  = 14 and write(2, "couldn't grab keyboard:", 23) = 23"

Comment: typo correction: the shortcut command is `/bin/sh ~/test.sh`

Comment: `"couldn't grab keyboard:"`I have researched a bit, it seems to be a bug. The last release is 12 years old.

Comment: The problem was gnome-screenshot -a failed too with different error. Or do you know how can i find the command bind to the default shortcut "Save a screenshot of an area to Pictures" ? /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.gschema.xml only give me something like `<key type="s" name="area-screenshot">
      <default>'&lt;Shift&gt;Print'</default>
      <summary>Take a screenshot of an area</summary>
      <description>Binding to take a screenshot of an area.</description>
    </key>` but there's no information about the command it bind to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, i tried strace parent processes like systemd and Xorg.bin, but i'm new to strace so i can't figure out.

Then i thought it might related to permission issue (su -, sudo, ...etc). So i plan to press the shortcut key as root. So i quickly realized i can use `sudo xdotool key Super+s` to test it. Then what's surprising me it just works!

So i try `xdotool key Super+s` without sudo and it still works. So i concluded that `xdotool key Super+s` is working fine, but still i can't figure out what's the difference between xdotool and key pressed from the strace log.

Then i come out an idea what if i put `xdotool key Super+s` as a custom shortcut ? So i created a new custom shortcut **Super+J** and bind to command `xdotool key Super+s`, in which **Super+s** already bind to command `scrot -s`. And it just works when i press **Super+j**

I tested `gnome-screenshot -a` and `scrot -s` and both works like a charm.

**[UPDATE]** I found this [link](https://code.google.com/p/xmonad/issues/detail?id=476), **Issue 476:   Xmonad should release key binding before spawning**:

> Reported by JohnTy...@gmail.com, Sep 18, 2011
>
> Using scrot here to take screen shots. Scrot grabs the keyboard to
>   listen for a keypress as a signal to abort. If the keyboard is not
>   avaiable, it dies with error:
>
> `giblib error: couldn't grab keyboard:Resource temporarily
>   unavailable`
>
> To test:
>
> bind "scrot -s > /tmp/logfile" to a keypress in xmonad.hs
>
> Activate keypress, nothing happens.
>
> Check logfile, find error stated above.
>
> I think it's a race condition because binding to "sleep 0.2; scrot -s"
>   works here.  The real problem is that xmonad is unnecessarily hanging
>   on to keyboard and the spawned app is expecting it.
>
> **What version of the product are you using? On what operating system?**
>   0.9.2/slackware linux

He use `sleep` to solve the similar problem. I tested it and it works. But I've to put it inside a shell script because custom command doesn't seems to support **&&** or **;** for concatenating multiple commands. But the time period of sleep 0.2 sometime doesn't work for me. The safe way is of course increase to sleep 0.5-1 second.