# How to define a custom screenshot in Gnome 3 and to assign it to a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, screenshot

I work under Debian Testing with Gnome shell 3.14.2 on a Lenovo
Thinkpad X1 Carbon (3rd gen.). I would like to create a custom
'screenshot' command based on scrot:

```
scrot -s -b '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_screenshot.png' -e 'mv $f ~/Myfolder'
```

I put this line in a file `.scrot.sh` and created the Shortcut
command via `/bin/sh ~/scrot.sh`. Furthermore, I uses "Print" as
the triggering shortcut (so simply pressing <kbd>PrtScn</kbd>). However, no
screenshot is produced. Why? And how can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... the bug behind is pretty bad... I found [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191973/how-to-create-custom-shortcuts-for-scrot-and-gnome-screenshot-interactive-mode) which links to [enter link description here](https://code.google.com/p/xmonad/issues/detail?id=476). To make it short, the command is indeed `/bin/sh /path/to/script` where `script` is a shell script containing

```
scrot -s -b '%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S_screenshot.png' -e 'mv $f /home/$USER/Myfolder'
```

... but assigning this to a shortcut via `Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> Custom Shortcuts` did not work because of a bug in `scrot` (?); see the above links. A workaround was to add `sleep 1;` right before `scrot...`. So this works for now. Pretty bad hack, though.